# Не отображается фото в MediaElement

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

Пытаюсь вывести jpg картинку в `MediaElement`, но при открытии приложения она не отображается. В Blend все выглядит нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Код  `MediaElement`:

```
<MediaElement Height="494" Margin="162,47,144.999,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="photo.jpg"/>
```

Comment: photo.jpg добавлено в проект? Или просто лежит отдельным файлом?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не выставили для **photo.jpg** `BuildType`. В свойствах поставьте `BuildType=Content` и будет вам счастье